# Dynamic default value for select list

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am trying to make a reservation system for equipment in a laboratory.
People reserve equipment by creating "reservation" nodes that are tagged with the taxonomy term "Equipment".
In the "create reservation page" the referenced taxonomy field is a dropdown list.

On the other hand I have a table view with all the equipment with its corresponding taxonomy term. 
I would like to have in a third column a link to the "create reservation page" and  I would like that in the "create reservation page"  the corresponding taxonomy term in the dropdown list is already selected.
Any idea how to succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Prepopulate](https://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module allows you to construct a special URL inside your table view that, when clicked, will prepopulate the correct taxonomy term on the "Create reservation page".

The special URL will looking something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/node/add/reservation?edit[field_equipment_term_reference]=123
```

You need to:

1. Download and install the Prepopulate Drupal module.
2. In your table view, add the Taxonomy Term ID field (if not already added).
3. In your table view, add a Global Text custom field.
4. In the Global Text field config screen, specify the text "create reservation page" and then expand the rewriting section, and turn the field into a link, with link destination of `node/add/reservation?edit[field_equipment_term_reference]=[tid]`.

Please note:

- the `[tid]` is the substitution token from the field added in step 2.
- replace `field_equipment_term_reference` with the real machine name of the taxonomy term reference field you're using on the Reservation node.